# read-only file system - network share

Tags: networking, fstab, read-only

I've been reading regarding read-only file system posts, but the ones I found relate to HDD/SDD's.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 on my laptop. I have a VM on my server (actual server) and running OMV. All files work well, except a few which give back read-only file system.
In the end what I'm trying to do is synchronizing my files from OMV to Google Drive with Grive2.

In my fstab I have the following:
[screenshot fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeLVj.png)

I tried to change file_mode=0777 and dir_mode=0777 to simply rw, but that didn't work, so I set it back. My /root/.smbcredentialsomv are correct as well (that's where it refers to). If this wasn't correct I wouldn't be able to access any files in the first place I assume.

I read to run fsck from a live USB, but as my drive is a network share and not on my local machine, I'm not sure if that's going to make sense. Feel free to correct me as I'm still learning.

In case you need to any more info to help solve this challenge, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Permissions of the network share are controlled by the remote server.  Also, CIFS does not handle multiple credentials on the same connection, so it is unsuitable for a multi-user share.

Comment: I understand what you're saying that CIFS does not handle multiple credentials on the same connection, but all credentials are the same. Both on my laptop as on the server. Will that make a difference or will it still not like it?

Comment: It isn't clear from your question which files are read only.  Is it all files in a specific mount, or some files in a specific directory, or are some files in a directory read only while others are writiable?  If this was a permissions issue, you would get a permission denied.  Read only filesystem indicates that the server is denying the write, but it should be for everything in the mount.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It are just a few files in about 10 sub folders who give the read-only. Obviously I have much more folders and files, but only these give a problem. I would expect all files would give the same problem or none. Not just a few files.

Comment: If it is only a few files, you need to investigate the permissions on those files on the server side.  Likely they are not writable with the credentials you are using for the mount.

Comment: When I try to change permissions with: chmod 777 <filename> I get the read-only file system :-(

Comment: Are you getting read only filesystem on the server?  Investigating or changing permissions on the client side is useless because CIFS doesn't support permissions or credentials on the client side.

Comment: And OpenMediaVault is a Debian based solution, not Ubuntu, therefore off-topic here. That you're using an Ubuntu client to access it is irrelevant for the suitability of this question to the website. You may want to post at Unix&Linux.

Comment: Appologies ChanganAuto.
@user10489: yes, on the server
Problem has been solved: I've rebooted the server and somehow the problem has been solved... No clue why though... Sorry to keep everybody busy...

Comment: Problem is solved... Apparently while updating my fstab file, by accident I changed the IP address from 192 to 191 for homebase. Oops... My bad...

Answer (score 0):

In the linked image, all the network filesystems are using the CIFS network filesystem.

In general, the CIFS protocol supports only a single credential per connection, and does not support unix style permissions.  Any unix permissions visible on the client side are simulated, and changing them does not work (or does not work as expected) because either they don't exist server side or are translated from server permissions that don't have a 1:1 mapping.

The error "read only filesystem" indicates the server is refusing the write, and the problem is either on the server or in the way the filesystem is mounted.  If this was a problem with the mount itself, all the files in the mount should be read only.

If this was a permission problem, you would get "permission denied".

Since the server is not running Ubuntu, resolving this issue on the server side is off topic here.